# Create a 2D array with 2 columns from a dataframe and loop for value

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, loops

I have a huge dataframe which looks like this:

```py
    u_id  i_id  
0  55218    0      
1  55218    2       
2  55218    1       
3  55222    2 
4  55222    3
```

I want to create an array with the axes `u_id` and `i_id` and the value is `1` (if `u_id` has the `i_id`) and `0` otherwise.
Like that:

```py
    0    1    2    3
0   1    1    1    0
1   0    0    1    1
```

I created the array with:

```py
df_neu = np.full(df[['u_id', 'i_id']].nunique(), 0)
```

but now I don't know how to overwrite `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
df = df.groupby('u_id')['i_id'].apply(list).reset_index()
def fill(x):
    for val in x.i_id:
        df_un[x.name,val] = 1
df.apply(lambda x: fill(x), axis=1)

print(df_un)

[[1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 1 1]]
```

Comment: what's df_un? a new dataframe?

Comment: Its the same numpy array that you created `df_neu = np.full(df[['u_id', 'i_id']].nunique(), 0)' .. I just renamed if df_un.. I was trying to build on top of yours.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this

```
columns = sorted(set(df['i_id'].values))
df_neu = pd.DataFrame({key: [1 if c in group['i_id'].values else 0
                             for c in columns]
                       for key, group in df.groupby('u_id')},
                      index=columns).T
```

essentially leads to your expected result:

```
       0  1  2  3
55218  1  1  1  0
55222  0  0  1  1
```

My assumption is that your original DataFrame is named `df`.

If you want to get rid of the `u_id` index:

```
df_neu.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

```
   0  1  2  3
0  1  1  1  0
1  0  0  1  1
```

Or a without the transposing:

```
columns = sorted(set(df['i_id'].values))
df_neu = pd.DataFrame([[1 if c in group['i_id'].values else 0
                        for c in columns]
                       for _, group in df.groupby('u_id')],
                      columns=columns)
```