# change the value of an array if number is in row of an dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```py
   'id'  'num'
0  54    [2,2,3,1] 
1  55    [2,1,2,2,2]       
2  58    [1,2,2,2]       
3  552   [1,4,3]
```

and an array like this:

```py
   0    1    2    3    4 
0  0    0    0    0    0      
1  0    0    0    0    0
2  0    0    0    0    0      
3  0    0    0    0    0
```

I created the dataframe with:

```py
df = data.groupby('id')['num'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

and the array with:

```py
df_neu = np.full(data[['id', 'num']].nunique(), 0)
```

I want to change the value of the dataframe so that its '1' if e.g. the number '2' is in the column 'num' for '54' in column 'id' else '0'

Like that:

```py
   0    1    2    3     
0  1    1    1    0      
1  1    1    0    0
2  1    1    0    0      
3  1    0    1    1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try (similar to my suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64782532/create-a-2d-array-with-2-columns-from-a-dataframe-and-loop-for-value/64828183#64828183)):

```
columns = sorted(set().union(*(num for num in df['num'].values)))
df_neu = pd.DataFrame({key: [1 if c in df['num'].loc[i] else 0
                             for c in columns]
                       for i, key in zip(df.index, df['id'].values)},
                      index=columns).T
```

Result:

```
     1  2  3  4
54   1  1  1  0
55   1  1  0  0
58   1  1  0  0
552  1  0  1  1
```

I think that transforming the original DataFrame `df` first would be a good idea (performance-wise):

```
df['num'] = df['num'].transform(set)
```

Here's a version without the transposing, which is probably better:

```
df['num'] = df['num'].transform(set)  # Not necessary
columns = sorted(set().union(*(num for num in df['num'].values)))
df_neu = pd.DataFrame([[1 if c in df['num'].loc[i] else 0
                        for c in columns]
                       for i, key in zip(df.index, df['id'].values)])
```